# Problems with REST deployment on IIS7

Tags: .net, rest, iis-7

I can't get my REST service to run on IIS7.

It runs fine from VisualStudio 2010 ASP.NET Development Server.

But on IIS i get "HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found".

I'm guessing it has something to do with the URL routing? How can I verify this?

Happy to give more details about the problem if it can help anyone help me.

Comment: What mode is your application pool running in?

Comment: @Andrey It's running under Integrated mode

Comment: Do you get the 404 with GET? Or only with PUT and DELETE verbs?